# Exchange mailbox for Dynamics 365 trial

Tags: dynamics-crm, exchange-server, dynamics-365

Is it possible to have a trial exchange mailbox for user for the Dynamics 365 trial account? I can set up a shared mailbox, but seems unable to add any member to the shared mailbox or creating another mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can purchase a trial Office 365 Plan 1. After success, you can use it.